# android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos creator. I am working on a game and when I press home button and get back to app, the app is crashed. It shows this error while debugging:

> android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9 in tid 27173
>   (GLThread 1836)

I have already searched a lot. But I dont understand what to do.

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74446000 in tid 13424
>   (GLThread 785)
>
> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x48 in tid 21741
>   (RenderThread) in android in rear case in some device

If someone can explain me in simple words what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too little information to answer. You could show us the code that is crashing. Maybe you are using a null pointer

Comment: I am new so i don't know really what to post here.

Comment: Check what version of OS you are testing on and what phone.  I found these crashes to only occur on Samsucks S8 or S7

Answer (score 0):

Debugging Cocos2D-X on Android is a little bit harder than iOS, but you could use ADB tools to check the logs printed on logcat.

First [start Android ADB Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html) and filter logcat to show only Errors from your PID or package name.
When a fatal error occurs you'll see the stacktrace with file names and line numbers. This way you'll also see errors generated by Java code